# tcolorbox + minted + "listing file" in a subdirectory

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I have a document with a *lot* of listings that need to get written out to files, and I want those generated listing files to be in a subdirectory of my document's main directory.  For example, if my main document is `project/main.tex`, I want all the listings to go into the directory `project/generated`.

I can't seem to make this work with tcolorbox and minted.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[outputdir=mweout]{minted}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted,raster,skins,xparse}

\NewTCBListing{mylisting}{ O{} }{
  listing only,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[listing file=mweout/listing]
  \LaTeX is fun.
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

Using lualatex and MacTeX 2017, I get:

```
$ mkdir mweout
$ lualatex --shell-escape mwe.tex 2>&1 </dev/null
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
 system commands enabled.
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
[... snipping a bunch of files being loaded, I think...]
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbminted.code.tex' version '4.10'
[... more snipping...]
/Users/dale/.vpy/default/bin/pygmentize

No file mwe.aux.
[... more snipping...]
(./_minted-mwe/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (./_minted-mwe/default.pygstyle)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mwe.pyg'
Error: cannot read infile: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mwe.pyg'

! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 \end{mylisting}

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.18 \end{mylisting}

 442 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 3 dir, 7 attribute, 59 glue_spec, 7 attribute_list, 2 temp,
 2 write, 1 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:20,3:4,4:2,7:2,8:1,9:2
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

If you take `mweout` out of `listing file`, it works, of course.  Uncommenting the `\usepackage[outputdir=mweout]{minted}` doesn't help, I get a similar error.

How can I have listings in tcblisting output to a subdirectory and formatted by minted?

I'm not sure whether tcolorbox issues [9](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/9) and/or [12](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/12) may be relevant here but I couldn't discern any useful help from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the `mweout` directory, you'll find the file `listing.tex`. It's the file where your listing is temporarily saved by `LaTeX`. The `.tex` extension is added automagically. However, minted tries to find `mweout/listing` without any extension and fails. To make things work just add any extension to the `listing file` option. For example, the following code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,raster,skins,xparse}

\NewTCBListing{mylisting}{ O{} }{
  listing only,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mylisting}[listing file=mweout/listing.tex]
  \LaTeX is fun.
\end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```